# Visualize data over a map using Gephi

Tags: visualization, gephi

I am trying to visualize my data (in CSV format) over a map. However I don't know what specific structure should I import it in Gephi.

A normal CSV data-set is split up into a node- and an edge table. A node table has column headers `id, label` and edge table has `source, target, weight`.

To visualize it over a map where should I enter the coordinates (latitude and longitude). Consider the visualization to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visualize network above a world map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541611/visualize-network-above-a-world-map)

Answer (score 1):

> But to visualize it over a map where should I enter the coordinates of latitude and longitudes.

you should compute the corresponding latitude and longitude of node and set them as new columns in the `Node` table or create a new csv file with `Id`(map to the original Node table) and another two columns named `Latitude` & `longitude`;
*remember to set the data type of you `Latitude` & `longitude` as double*

after you import the csv file to Gephi, in the layout you may use geolayout which can show you what you want.

for detail tutorial you can visit [gephi tutorial](http://www.martingrandjean.ch/gephi-introduction/)